# Why the RotatingFileHandler does not inherit the log format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

In the console I can see the logging messages formatted in the way I specified. However when I inspect the log file all I can see is the `message` part of original log entries.

Here is how I set up the logger when the program starts

```
LOG_FORMAT="%(asctime)-15s pid %(process)6d tid %(thread)4d %(levelname)-8s %(module)-8s %(message)s"

logging.basicConfig(format=LOG_FORMAT)
file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile_name)
logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

How can make the file logger also respect the format setting?

Answer (score 1):

You can set formatter of file_handler:

```
file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile_name)
formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

More details on [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging)

Comment: I am wishing for a simpler solution which will allow the file handler to automatically inherit the settings from the `basicConfig()` call. I will try out your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: The [API doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) says "The functions debug(), ...... will call basicConfig() automatically if no handlers are defined for the root logger". As I understood, the handlers you added to a logger do not inherit from basicConfig. So probably that way cannot work